# I was a victim of fraud and mean to turn the fraudster in- how?

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud

Long story short:

a gutter cleaner drops a leaflet with phone number, and as my gutters needed to be cleaned I called him, we met and I gave him a deposit for the work in cash. The gutter cleaner put everything in writing at the back of the leaflet and signed it. Gutter cleaner never shows up for the work. I only have his number and mean to ask my friend to call him because they need their gutters cleaned too, so as to lure him into a trap. But then- how do I turn him into the police and keep everything legal? Was thinking of using pepper spray, but I live in Newcastle, and it's illegal to use it in the UK. Any ideas?

Comment: You report it to the police, nothing else. Don't even think of trying to apprehend them yourself.

Comment: The police may say "It's a civil matter, have a word with a solicitor." If so, decide for yourself whether to chase the cleaner through the courts for your money, but don't even think of trapping him.

Comment: But whyever not?

Comment: Because no crime that he has (may have) committed justifies illegal conduct by you. What you are suggesting sounds like entrapment, fraud and assault, and is almost certainly enough for a defence lawyer to introduce reasonable doubt. Don't try to do the police's job unless you know the limits they work under.

Answer (score 4):

> a gutter cleaner drops a leaflet with phone number, and as my gutters needed to be cleaned I called him, we met and I gave him a deposit for the work in cash. The gutter cleaner put everything in writing at the back of the leaflet and signed it.

In other words, you have a written contract which you fulfilled but the other party did not fulfill, so they now either owe you a service or your money back. This is a civil law matter [which you can bring to a county court](https://www.gov.uk/make-court-claim-for-money). You have a telephone number, so it should be possible to identify the other party.

> lure him into a trap. But then- how do I turn him into the police and keep everything legal? Was thinking of using pepper spray, but I live in Newcastle, and it's illegal to use it in the UK. Any ideas?

This is a very bad idea!

Apprehending suspects is the job of the police, not yours. Well, there is the concept of a [citizen's arrest](https://www.inbrief.co.uk/police/citizens-arrest/), but this is only an option in a very limited number of cases, specifically when you catch a criminal in the act and need to prevent the suspect from getting away before the police arrives. And even then you are on very shaky legal ground if the suspect claims you used more force than necessary or if the court doubts that a citizen's arrest was necessary in this particular case.

And in this case a court probably won't believe that a citizen's arrest is justified, because the gutter cleaner probably didn't even commit a crime. They just violated a contract. That's a civil matter, not a criminal matter. It *might* be a criminal matter if they never intended to fulfill the contract (fraud), but you don't know that. If you use violence on a person just because they owe you money, you are very likely committing a crime yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You contact **Newcastle Trading Standards**. Contact info is on this page although they will probably try to refer you to Citizens' Advice Bureau for 'consumer advice'. Trading Standards is the enforcing authority.

https://www.newcastle.gov.uk/business/trading-standards/fair-trading

(This assumes you are Newcastle-upon-Tyne and not another Newcastle)